# Key stuck in door lock

Tags: repair, doors

My key is stuck in the door lock and won't come out. I have tried numerous ways and it just won't. Any ideas on how to get it out or what can be done?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the key stuck at that angle, or does it rotate at all?

Comment: It is stuck at an angle

Comment: Is that one of those "rekeyable" locks? I see those two dots are aligned in your pic, this would be the position for rekeying it with the master key. Could be a problem with that...

Comment: @dotjoe explain more. I don't know if it is rekeyable but interested in your thoughts.

Comment: Quickest might be removing deadbolt from the door and have a locksmith or hardware store pull the pins and free it.  Twisting it too hard might damage the inside of the cylinder or if a pin has come too far out, mangle the spring.  Might be time to get a new key too, if it is too worn as it could have caused this issue.

Comment: They sell some locks that can be re-keyed with a master key. Typically there will be two dots that you can align when turning the master key to a 45 degree angle. I bought one once and had nothing but problems with it after I re-keyed a couple times. Did you inherit this lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all the great suggestions above and failing, I ended up calling a locksmith.  He fixed it in 15 minutes by taking the lock apart.  As it turned out, one of the pins in the 6-pin lock was tilted and not letting the barrel move.  That was it.  Hopefully, this answer will help someone else in a similar situation

Comment: Did you need to change the lock? Or was it possible just to repair the lock?

Comment: Nope.  The locksmith adjusted/aligned the pins and that's all it took to fix it

Answer (score 5):

Don't laugh, this may work as I have used it on stuck or cross-threaded bolts and locks. Remember that heat makes metals expand, while cold makes metals contract. Looks like the usual 5-pin tumbler lock.
 I do not know how the key is stuck, but brass is a soft metal. After long term use the surface can becomes rounded and not move the tumblers correctly. The tumblers could be stuck from dirt or other contaminants.
 Try oiling the key first by forcing WD-40 or a light motor oil into the lock and tap the key *lightly* with a *small* hammer. This will normally loosen a stuck pin tumbler. Next step is to by freeze-spray and freeze *only the key*. This will make the key shrink a tiny bit.
 Wiggle the key and latch to try and jar the pin tumblers loose. Brass is not brittle when cold but do not use enough power to break the key. I am assuming someone did not play a dirty prank and put super-glue inside the lock. Even so, oil, freezing and heating will make the key loosen up, even if it takes a few hours.

Comment: For sure this was not a prank.  We started having the issue but were able to get the key out.  One fine day it refuses to come out.  Will try out your suggestions

Comment: @JStorage. That's the way it usually happens. No warning - it just gets stuck. Once the WD-40 has had time to settle in, I would not use any more force than pulling and wiggling the key with pliers, pushing in and pulling out. As I mentioned in my answer, brass is tough but has its limits. Use 50-weight motor oil for a long term lube. It stays in place and will not turn into a hard powder like graphite can.

Comment: Strong disagreement re oil on something whose tolerances are measured in thousandths of an inch, but that's the religious debate again and people believe what they want to believe.

Answer (score 1):

(can't see the images as I am at work)
I had a key get stuck in a lock half rotated once.  I forget exactly what happed.  I believe it has something to do with ability to set the lock for a different key, one of the pieces got jammed.  I ended up disassembling the entire lock and reassembling.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities.

One, that everyone else has been pursuing, is that the lock cylinder itself is binding. If so, lubrication and/or vibration may help loosen it.

If you think it might have been super glued, you can try acetone, which dissolves cyanoacrylate glues -- but it may also dissolve the finish on the lock, and on the door, and on anything else it drips on. Personally I'd consider replacing the cylinder in that case.

Which brings us to the other possibile approach: Open the door from inside, and disassemble/dismount the lock far enough to remove the cylinder. If it turns freely by itself, the latch mechanism was jammed; check that the latch is engaging the strike without side pressure and is operating smoothly. If the cylinder still doesn't turn, you can get a replacement and worry about unsticking this one later, and/or bring the cylinder to a locksmith for assistance. Much cheaper than asking the locksmith to come to you, much easier than bringing her the whole door...

Answer (score 0):

Graphite lube is better than WD-40 for locks... try a product called lock-ease. Use a rubber mallet and whack it hard many times while turning and jiggling the key. Don't hit the key, when hammering. Keep turning-pressure on the key while hammering and jiggling.

[image]

Edit-

You *can* use WD-40 in a pinch, if you don't have graphite, but you should then use copious amount of lock-ease to rinse out the oil or take the lock off the door out and rinse it with a solvent like acetone whithin a few months. Use graphite for lubricating locks, not oil or products like WD-40 which will collect dust and eventually dry, leaving a gummed up lock.

You should also get a new key cut, because the primary reason for keys getting stuck is that they have been worn down too low. Keys are basically "digital". So a new key should fit better.

Edit: If you have powdered graphite you may need to suspend it in isopropyl alcohol. A 5%-10% solution (by weight) should work, but measuring could be an issue, so another way to do this is to put some graphite in a baggie, and then add 90% isopropyl alcohol to it. Use as little alcohol as possible to make a suspension. The suspension should be runny enough to be sucked up with a dropper.

Where to apply lubricant:

[image]

Comment: Graphite is a better lubricant, and so is heavy motor oil, but this needed the rust and dirt cutting ability of WD-40 to start with. A good oiling comes after the lock is fixed.

Comment: @Sparky256 Lock ease is made of light-weight alkanes, acetone, and graphite; it only leaves graphite as a residue. WD-40 leaves oil-gum, surfactants, and waxes which will mess up a lock. Locks rarely have rust issues because they are made of brass and stainless steel. Keys get stuck because they are either worn out or because of gums left from stuff like WD-40. The best way to clean up a lock that has been gummed up by WD-40 is to use something like lock ease which contains acetone, heptane, and octane, which will rinse out the gunk and leave only graphite behind. In an emergency, WD-40 is ok.

Comment: @sparky256 MSDS for lock ease: http://agscompany.com/images/stories/MSDS/English/Lock-Ease-Aerosol_LE-5_English.pdf

Comment: @Sparky256 MSDS for WD-40: http://wd40.com/files/pdf/msds-wd482671453.pdf

Comment: Lock-ease versus WD40 versus graphite (used properly)  is a long-standing religious debate; we aren't going to resolve it here. In my experience it usually doesn't make much difference, though I prefer a silicon microsphere lube to any of these if I have it available.

Comment: @keshlam Went searching for religion... found this "scientific" study enlightening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZaPWGo8TbE  It seems that plain old graphite does work the best, or ties with Dupont brand PTFE (but other bands of PTFE did not work quite as well).

Comment: As I said, religion. People don't want to her confused by facts. My one objection to graphite is that it is far easier to overapply, and causes more trouble when overapplied in many locks, than the others... So I tend not to suggest it for amateurs. And I treat WD40 as a cleanser rather than a lube.

Comment: @keshlam. That is how I treat WD-40. I do not consider it a lubricant as it does not have enough viscosity to stay in place.

Comment: @BenWelborn I bought some graphite from a big box store.  How do I apply it with the key already stuck.  Are you suggesting I apply it after I manage to get the key out?  Tried hammering and it has not worked yet. Will keep trying by hammering harder

Comment: @JStorage There are graphite sprays, and graphite powder in tubes. Powder would be more difficult to use with a key already in the hole, so if that is what you purchased, then I would recommend suspending the powder in isopropyl alcohol (90% preferable to 70%), and use a dropper or something with a narrow spout to apply the suspended graphite to the key hole. I will edit my answer to provide more exact details, shortly.